# I want to perfect forward variadic arguments except for a specific type

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers, c++14, perfect-forwarding

I have the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

template<typename _type>
class handle
{
  using ptr = std::shared_ptr<_type>;
  using pptr = std::shared_ptr<ptr>;
public:
  handle(handle<_type> const & other) :
    mData(make_pptr(*(other.mData)))
  {}


  handle(_type && data) :
    mData(make_pptr(std::move(data)))
  {}
private:
  pptr mData;

  template<typename ..._args>
  constexpr auto make_ptr(_args && ...args)
  {
    return std::make_shared<_type>(std::forward<_args>(args)...);
  }

  constexpr auto make_pptr(ptr const & pointer)
  {
    return std::make_shared<ptr>(pointer);
  }

  template<typename ..._args>
  constexpr auto make_pptr(_args && ...args)
  {
    return std::make_shared<ptr>(make_ptr(std::forward<_args>(args)...));
  }
};

int main()
{
  handle<int> h = 5;
  handle<int> h2(h);
}
```

Compiled with `g++-4.9 --std=c++14 -O0  -o main main.cpp` the code

```
handle<int> h2(h);
```

does not compile. The problem functions are all the overloads of

```
make_pptr
```

As I understand it, the template function will always be chosen, as the compiler tries to find the **most** specialized function call and the perfect forwarding creates exactly that.

I found the following two pages who seem to handle that problem with the type trait `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same`.

https://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/too-perfect-forwarding/

http://www.codesynthesis.com/~boris/blog/2012/05/30/perfect-forwarding-and-overload-resolution/

The actual question is, how can I change this function, so that the non-template functions will be called if I pass the factory function an already existing pointer?

Is there a common way to do it?

Comment: What is `T` ? Are you in a template class ?

Comment: What exactly isn't working the way you want it to? Partial ordering should ensure the correct function template gets picked when you pass an lvalue/rvalue `shared_ptr`. Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) of the case that doesn't work?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: can you specify what the problem with the question is?

Comment: @Jarod42: Yes this is a template class with these functions, I updated the question.

Comment: @Praetorian: The template function is always called even if I pass a shared_ptr, the two articles I added cover exactly that topic but one is about perfect forwarding constructors and the other one, I dont know why just does not work for me.

Comment: @Praetorian: I added my complete example.

Comment: Following works [Demo](https://ideone.com/ZG9xbY)

Comment: @Jarod42: The compile error occurs when using `auto cp = std::make_shared<int>(42);` instead of `const auto cp...`

Comment: I downvoted this.  If you care and want to revert that downvote, my problem with the above post is that you didn't produce a minimal example of your error, not even close.   Instead you copy/pasted the code you had a problem with (for a gross example, `is_valid` is never called).  Please try to generate minimal examples of your problem before posting.  You can include a link to a more full set of code for context, or have the more full set of code in an "appendix" at the bottom of your post.  If you clean your post up to being minimal, @Yakk me and I will revert (and possibly upvote!)

Comment: @Yakk: I think I removed everything which has nothing to do with the example, and it yields the same error. When I add the code which resolved my issue from the answer below it works as expected. I hope this is conform with the guidelines.

Comment: Yes, that is much much better!  I would still kill `operator type_&` or `operator*`.  I'd even be tempted to kill both, `operator bool`, and the printing bit, and just mention that you are doing this in order to do a smart pointer, but having your code do something is also worthwhile.

Comment: @Yakk: I also removed the other stuff and tested it. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jarod's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30468114/241631) explains, in the constructor

```
handle(handle<_type> const & other) :
  mData(make_pptr(*(other.mData)))
{}
```

you call `make_pptr` with an argument of type `shared_ptr<_type>&`, which makes the perfect forwarding overload of `make_pptr` a better match than the one that takes a `shared_ptr<_type> const&`. You can cast the argument to `const&` as he shows, or you could add another overload of `make_pptr` that takes a non-`const` lvalue reference.

```
constexpr auto make_pptr(ptr & pointer)
{
  return std::make_shared<ptr>(pointer);
}
```

Yet another option is to constrain the perfect forwarding overload so that it is viable only when the first argument of the parameter pack is not a `shared_ptr<_type>`.

Some helpers to evaluate whether the first type in the parameter pack is a `shared_ptr<T>`

```
namespace detail
{
    template<typename... _args>
    using zeroth_type = typename std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<_args...>>::type;

    template<typename T, bool eval_args, typename... _args>
    struct is_shared_ptr
    : std::false_type
    {};

    template<typename T, typename... _args>
    struct is_shared_ptr<T, true, _args...>
    : std::is_same<std::decay_t<zeroth_type<_args...>>,
                   std::shared_ptr<T>
                  >
    {};
}
```

Then constrain the perfect forwarding `make_pptr` as follows

```
template<typename ..._args,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<
                        not detail::is_shared_ptr<_type, sizeof...(_args), _args...>::value
                    >
        >
constexpr auto make_pptr(_args && ...args)
{
  return std::make_shared<ptr>(make_ptr(std::forward<_args>(args)...));
}
```

---

I also had to change your `make_ptr` overload because the way you have it defined in your example requires that `_type` be constructible from `nullptr`.

```
constexpr auto make_ptr()
{
  return std::make_shared<_type>();
  // no nullptr arg above, shared_ptr default ctor will initialize _type* to nullptr
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6f7425ae072514a)

Comment: This actually solves my problem, but a little question remains. When I call the function without arguments `make_pptr()`, it does not compile. When I remove the part after the logical `||` operator it works fine. So I guess the problem is that the logical operator evaluates both parts even if the first part succeeds. I thought this usually is not the case. I tested it in your code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0652cf1112137036

Comment: @satanik Sorry, that was my screw up. The whole expression needs to be valid even if the second part is not evaluated, that's why it wouldn't compile when the parameter pack was empty. I've added an extra level of indirection so that you don't go querying the first type in the pack when the pack is empty.

Comment: It works like a charm, but can you explain what happens with the structs `is_shared_ptr`? I think I cannot fully understand. `zeroth_type` extracts the first type of the type list. `is_shared_ptr` seems to make the `is_same` comparison, but both inherit from either `false_type` or `true_type` and why use the `false_type`? And what is the `size_of` for?

Comment: @satanik The primary `is_shared_ptr` template is matched when `eval_args` is `false`, i.e. `sizeof...(_args)==0`. In that case we know the first type in the (empty) parameter pack is not `shared_ptr`, so we inherit from `false_type`. The partial specialization of `is_shared_ptr` is matched when `sizeof...(_args)!=0`, and then we inherit from `true_type` or `false_type` depending on whether the first type in the pack is a `shared_ptr<_type>`.

Comment: +1 for use of `not`.  But I'd have made two perfect forwarding functions, one with `args&&...` and one with `arg&&`, and only tested for a shared ptr in the `arg` case.  A class `X` that takes as a ctor `(shared_ptr<X>,int)` would be blocked by the above code, no?  In my case, only `X(shared_ptr<X>)` gets blocked.  A more robust solution would also deal with the possibility that you'd be passed a `shared_ptr<Derived>` when you are storing a `shared_ptr<Base>`.

Comment: @Yakk That's an odd thing to get a +1 for :) Great idea about the two overloads, and yes, you're absolutely correct, the code above does break for constructors that take a `shared_ptr<self_type>` as the first argument. I'll post an update later today.

Answer (score 0):

When calling

```
handle<int> h2(h);
```

You call

```
handle(handle<_type> const & other) : mData(make_pptr(*(other.mData)))
{}
```

and `*other.mData` is a `std::shared_ptr<_type>&` and so you call

```
template<typename ..._args>
constexpr auto make_pptr(_args && ...args)
```

which is an exact match.

You may force the `const` with

```
handle(handle<_type> const & other) :
    mData(make_pptr(static_cast<const ptr&>(*(other.mData))))
{}
```

to solve your issue.

or add overload for simple reference.

Comment: I know that, but is there no other way to make the decision in the `make_pptr` function? Because this would be more clean I guess, and what I had intended when writing the overloads.

Comment: @satanik: You may use SFINAE as shown by Praetorian, but I'm not sure it is cleaner than the solution with the  non-const lvalue overload.